# Display sender name as set in message header, instead of full name from address book

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I came across this as the only other thing I could find that resembled what I'm asking: http://office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/t/84123/

I'm sending an email through Office 365's SMTP server as a notification that a form was submitted to my company email address (me@company.com) from our company RSVP email address (rsvp@company.com). I am setting the From Name to be the full name of the person filling out the form and the reply-to email as the person's email address textbox.

Here is an example of what part of the message header might look like:

```
To: <me@company.com>
From: Test User <rsvp@company.com>
Reply-To: <test.user@gmail.com>
```

In Outlook, since rsvp@company.com is an actual mailbox within our company, it automatically displays the sender name as "RSVP" (which I suppose is what was set when the mailbox was created). Is there a way to bypass this and display the sender name in the message header instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Exchange always resolves all sender and recipient names to their primary SMTP address and default name. Just the way Exchange works.

You can extract MIME headers and modify the message sender related properties on the client side after the message is received using Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author - use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`CreateOneOffEntryID` / [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`GetAddressEntryFromID` / set [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Sender` and [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).Get_`SentOnBehalfOf` / `RDOMail.Save`). Note that OOM will not let you set the sender related properties even using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor`.

Comment: I was hoping there was some setting hidden in Outlook that would allow this change, but I guess not. Thanks!